# Is there a way to add typescript definintions to the "window" object

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Visual Studio has most of the typescript definitions built into it for the window object because most all of them work.  However, "window.chrome" is not defined.  How can I add this to the existing typescript definitions so I can get Visual Studio to compile?

```
var isChromium = window.chrome;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `Window` interface anywhere in your code:

```
interface Window {
    chrome:any; //you can go further and define a strict shape of this member
}
```

Interface declarations can be split into multiple files - compiler will merge all interface declarations with the same name into single definition.

Comment: See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html